# Interior points/Boundary points of sets

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I need a little help understanding exactly what an interior & boundary point are/how to determine the interior points of a set. If you could help me understand why these are the correct answers or also give some more examples that would be great. Thanks~

a. $\{1/n\colon n\in \!\, \mathbb{N} \!\,\}$

interior= $\varnothing \!\,$

The reason that S has no interior points is that for each of its points 1/n, any open set containing 1n contains points that are not of the form 1/n.

boundary point=

b. $[0,3]\cup \!\,(3,5)$

interior= $(0,5)$

boundary point=

c.${r\in \!\,\mathbb{Q} \!\,:0<r<\sqrt2}$

interior= $\varnothing \!\,$

boundary point=

d. ${r\in \!\,\mathbb{Q} \!\ :r \ge\ \sqrt2}$

interior= $\varnothing \!\,$

boundary point=

e.$[0,2]\cap \!\,[2,4]$

interior= $\varnothing \!\,$

The reason that S has no interior points is that the intersection of [0,2] and [2,4] is 2, and for the point 2, any open set that contains 2 will contain points that are outside of the set.

boundary point=

Comment: Check the definition of interior point and use it to prove that the interior of those sets is what's suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Your stated reason for (a) is mistaken.  You said

> this because the only common value 1/n and the set of natural numbers have is 1

But this is confused.  Note that the given set (call it $S$) is $\left\{\frac1n\mid n\in \Bbb N\right\}$.  This is not the same as $\left\{\frac1n\mid \frac1n\in \Bbb N\right\}$.  The latter would be the set $\{1\}$.

The reason that $S$ has no interior points is that for each of its points $\frac1n$, any open set containing $\frac1n$ contains points that are not of the form $\frac1n$.  For example, $\frac12$ is not an interior point because any open set containing $\frac12$ must also contain some of the points that are between $\frac12$ and $\frac13$, which are not included in  $S$.

Your other answers for the interiors are correct, although perhaps not for the right reasons. (You didn't give any.)

Comment: Ok, but I still don't understand the reasoning for the second question, specifically why 5 is an interior point?

Comment: It isn't.  You wrote that the interior is $(0,5)$.  This is a shorthand notation for the set of all numbers greater than $0$ and less than $5$. it does not include $5$.